# How to use NetSpell library to return an array of related words?

Tags: c#, dictionary

is there a way to return an array of strings of words related to an input string like `unbox` using NetSpell. The function is expected to return `unboxed, unboxing` as long as the words contain the input word. Here is what i have tried with NetSpell

```
using System.Collections;
using NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary;

try
{
    WordDictionary dictionary = new WordDictionary();
    dictionary.DictionaryFile = "en-US.dic";
    dictionary.Initialize();
    string word = "unbox";
    ArrayList colls = dictionary.ExpandWord(new Word(word));
    foreach (var item in colls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
catch (Exception p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Message);
}
```

When I try to expand, it only returns `unbox`, help me figure out a way to use NetSpell to return an array of related words Thank You or any other C# dictionary library

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the library supports finding related words?

Comment: I thought `expandWord` returned related words

Comment: would you have an idea of a dictionary that does the same thing

Comment: Is there a documentation page you can link to that shows the usage of `ExpandWord`?

Comment: Yeah let me link it

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277/NetSpell-Spell-Checker-for-NET

Comment: `So, we expand the base word that matched by applying all the affix rules to get a list of all the possible words from that base word.` That is a sub section of a documentation on the CodeProject